# Boolean value as checkbox

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-form, zend-framework2

I want to add a boolean value to my Entity.

It looks like this:

```
namespace MyModule\MyClass\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Zend\Form\Annotation as Form;
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="mymodule_myclass")
 * @Form\Name("myclass")
 * @Form\Attributes({ "class": "form-horizontal" })
*/
class MyClass

 ...

 /**
 * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
 * @Form\Attributes({"type":"checkbox"})
 * @Form\Options({"label":"Revised"})
 *
 */
protected $revised = false;
```

Of course I want to display this variable as a checkbox. So I added the `@Form\Attributes`.

Unfortunately I get a

> "NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error"

Any ideas why that is and what I can do to fix it?

BTW: Altering the `type` attribute manually per Firebug turns the input field into a checkbox...

Comment: Can you plz post your eentire code
I think there is a problem with your namespace and annotations

Comment: i updated my question and put my header code in it. or what exactly do you need?

Comment: looks fine ... plz review your error log ... for what cause this internal 500 error

Comment: the error log says nothing... and in my vhost there is no other log file set... any ideas left?

Comment: 1.if your host is cPanel check cpanel error log

Comment: 2.check that a file named error_log is created beside your index.php or not

Comment: 3.ask your host manager to disbale eAcceleator

Comment: thanks for your effort, but: i'm currently local so no cPanel, no activated eAccelerator and also no error_log next to my index.php

Comment: Apache err log ?! Internal server error will log it some where

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use Zend-Checkbox and not change the type of the input.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
 * @Form\Options({"label":"My Boolean*"})
 * @Form\Type("Zend\Form\Element\Checkbox")
 */
protected $my_bool;
```